# Formula to check if one cell is within a range between two cells from a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula, cells

[image: Excel table]

Say I have the value in D2. I want to see if that value is within the ranges B2-C2, B3-C3, B4-C4 and B5-C5. If it is, I want to find a function that returns the text from A2:A5 where the value fits within the ranges.

I would then use these values in a future function.

So in my example the function would return "Text 1" and "Text 4".

Answer (score 0):

You did not mention the function which you want to pass the results to. So I'm not sure about the format, as your question might imply that you need 2 results in the same cell. I hope this is not the case.

You can do what you need using this formula (copy it down):

```
=IF(AND($D$2>=$B2;$D$2<=$C2);$A2;0)
```

Results:
[image]

Comment: Was the answer helpful?